# Odd sequence of ids in GAE JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

In Google App Engine JDO I'm using `IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE` to generate ID. I expect to see 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... sequence, but I have odd values (1, 3, 5, 7 ...) of id in database.

```
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The IDs are guaranteed to be unique but may not increase monotically .

Check discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/665e6fed09ee149e?pli=1